# How to run Android Automotive scripts

Tags: android, python, android-auto

I am trying to run/test these Python scripts that can be found here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Car/+/master/tools/emulator

But I am not sure how to run them. I have setup an emulator on Android Studio, as well as on my Android device via `adb`, but I can't seem to run test the scripts. Can someone explain/help how I can run these scripts?

Tried running on android studio via emulator
Tried via Adb connection to android device

I believe this is the main script that runs `vhal_emulator_test.py`

```
Connecting local port 46495 to remote port 33452 on default device
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./vhal_emulator_test.py", line 370, in <module>
    v = VhalTest(vhal_consts_2_0.vhal_types_2_0)
  File "./vhal_emulator_test.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._vhal = vhal_emulator.Vhal(types)
  File "/home/maasif/Desktop/Builds/Automotive/packages/services/Car/tools/emulator/vhal_emulator.py", line 268, in __init__
    for cfg in msg.config:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'
```